# aws-S3 Rails reading a image file in binary format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm currently working on an project which has implementation of an external api, and this api requires the image in binary format. The images are stored on s3, my question is how do read a  file in binary format directly from the s3 without using a temp folder on the local end, so that I can pass it as a body of the request, for accessing the image i'm using

`(s3client.buckets[ENV["AWS_S3_BUCKET"]].objects[params[:url].split("amazonaws.com/")[1]].read)`

Can anyone help me out.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Great question, wish someone would answer it!